# Show all languages in form using django-translations

Tags: django, django-i18n

I am using [django-translations](https://github.com/bbmokhtari/django-translations) for translating some fields of my model.
Using the Django Admin I can enter the translations and the form in the frontend shows the matching language values.

But I want to show **one field for each language** "similar" to the Django Admin, except I don't want to manually add the fields for non translated languages.

So if I have the languages `en (default)` and `de` I want to output `title` or `title_en` and `title_de` as fields.

I tried to add the translation fields myself e.g. `title_de` to the model, layout and meta class, but it didn't work.

How can I show all the fields for different languages simultaneously?

**Model**

```py
class Category(Translatable, MPTTModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    class Meta:
        # enforcing that there can not be two categories under a parent with same slug
        unique_together = ('slug', 'parent',)

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['title']

    class TranslatableMeta:
        fields = ['title', 'slug']
```

**Form**

```py
class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    use_required_attribute = False

    title = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = forms.SlugField(help_text=_('Will be generated automatically from the title'))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.form_action = '.'
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal form-bordered'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-3'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'

        self.helper.layout = self.__get_layout()
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['title'].required = True
        self.fields['slug'].required = True

    @staticmethod
    def __get_layout():
        layout = Layout(
            Field('title'),
            Field('title_de'),
            Field('slug', readonly=''),
            ButtonHolder(
                Submit('submit', _('Save'))
            )
        )

        return layout

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()

        return cleaned_data

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['title', 'slug']
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, you should be able to use [ModelForms](https://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html#modelforms)

Comment: Well this works for `django-modeltranslation` but not for `django-translations`.

Comment: Hu, sorry about that. What's up with `generate_translation_form`?

Comment: Tought about `generate_translation_form`. But this gives me a form to create entries for the table `translations_translation`. Which result in the fields `field`, `language` & `text`